# How to perform Client Side Encryption in iOS AWS SDK?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, cryptography, cross-platform

is it Available ? or should I choose my own algorithm to encrypt data and upload it to the S3-bucket? I'm having a requirement to create an application in multiplatform(android/C#/ios) in which we have to encrypt data and Store it to the server side  . . .

I've tried [this](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption/tree/master/iOS) library to encrypt data, but in iOS side, I'm having different results than others . . .

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded a video on aws s3 bucket with client side encryption using below code. We need the AES256 key and md5 key when going to upload content on aws.
First, add pod [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) .

Now generate the AES256 & md5 key from below code.

```
    let input: Array<UInt8> = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    let key: Array<UInt8> = [0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00]

    let iv: Array<UInt8> = AES.randomIV(AES.blockSize)

    do {
        let encrypted = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).encrypt(input)
        let base64String: String = encrypted.toBase64()!
        let md5Data = encrypted.md5()
        let md5DataBase64 = md5Data.toBase64()
        print("Encrypted:\(encrypted),\n Base64String:\(base64String)")
        print("md5:\(md5Data),\n md5String:\(md5DataBase64)")

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Now add below two lines in your upload request of aws.

`uploadRequest?.sseCustomerKey =  "Your base64 string of AES 256 key"
uploadRequest?.sseCustomerKeyMD5 = "Your base64 string of md5"`