# AWS client side encryption IOS(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

How can we do **client side encryption**(using a key, generated at client side) in Amazon S3 bucket in **ios using swift**.

[have a look on AWS client side encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html)  is this possible in IOS

Comment: What encryption are we looking at ? AES Encryption ?

Comment: @SankarNarayanan have edited my question please have a look on it.

Comment: Looks like the implementation is internal to SDK. It does not describe encryption technique or anything of that sort. What is the possibility (or) feasibility of writing a middleware (which sits between your device and AWS) in java to support this ?

Comment: yes it is supported in java. We just need to pass a key and AWS does encryption for us. SO is this possible in IOS does AWS IOS sdk supports this?

Comment: yes, It's possible to upload content on aws with client side encryption. I have answered this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45375752/6699642.